# Join two tables where there MAY or may not be values on the second one

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I know it must be a lot simpler than I'm going through...

On one table I have the available classes for the players to enroll, on the other one, once you are enrolled, I register the player there. Now, The problem lies when I want to select all public classes and enrolled classes where the player MAY or MAY NOT have been before.

If a player leaves the class, in order to keep their data, the second table just updates a field to "out" if she is enrolled, such field reads "in"

```
SELECT * FROM k3_pwl_br_classes a 
    JOIN k3_pwl_br_player_class b 
    ON a.class_id=b.class_id 
    WHERE
    (a.class_privacy = 'public')
    OR (b.player_id=51 AND b.player_class_status='in')
    OR (b.player_id=51 AND b.player_class_status='out' AND a.class_privacy='public')
    OR (a.class_owner=51 AND b.player_id=51)

    ORDER BY a.class_title, a.class_id
```

The result is ANY possible combination, so I have 3 users in the DB and they are enrolled in class 1 but NOT enrolled in class 2

Player 1 Owns class 1 which is PUBLIC
Player 46 Owns class 2 which is PUBLIC
Player 51 owns NO class.

Player 1 and 46 are enrolled in their classes
Player 51 is enrolled (player_class_status="in") in class 2 but left class 1(player_class_status='out')

When you login as player 51, you see class 2 three times and class 1 once.

If I remove

`(a.class_privacy = 'public')`

Then it won't show ANY results... The problem lies when the DB makes the JOIN the conditions are met 4 times... How do I SELECT all public classes and all enrolled classes without duplicating entries and making sure that IF the player_id is on the player_class table I get all the data?

I know it's easier but my head has been here for over a week :(

Thanks :)

Comment: Try a `LEFT JOIN` ? (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

Comment: You should maybe using th LEFT/RIGHT join in your query (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html). I'm not sure I understand your problem, a table with the class/player would help

Comment: I've added all possible JOINS and none work :( LEFT or RIGHT just get me either 4 rows or no rows... I need just one row per class and IF such player is or was enrolled in the class, that data

If I use LEFT JOIN it gets data from other player and that is not good, Such fields should be empty or NULL if player 51 was never in that class

Comment: Maybe reverse your query : `SELECT * FROM k3_pwl_br_player_class AS  b JOIN k3_pwl_br_classes AS a ON ....`

Comment: try left join and group by the column you want and so you'll get only one row.

Comment: Nope... Not working :( It does return 2 classes when not enrolled, but after one class enrollment, I get a duplicate on that class

Comment: If you are selecting all (with *), you are not getting "duplicate entries" as they differ by player info. If you only want class info, `SELECT DISTINCT a.*` instead.

Comment: That's the problem, I need the info from player_class when such data exists and every other public class So DISTINCT doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally found the solution. 
1) I was being redundant
2) I was VERY confused

The problem I needed to solve is this: I need to SELECT public and enrolled classes
Public classes may or may not include the user in the query, but non-public enrolled classes must bring all data...

Basically my query wasn't all wrong. IT should've look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM br_classes a 
LEFT JOIN br_player_class b 
ON a.class_id=b.class_id AND b.player_id=51
WHERE
(a.class_privacy = 'public')
OR (b.player_id51 AND b.player_class_status='in')
OR (a.class_owner=51)
```

The query retrieves all classes that are public with or without the user enrolled in it and all other classes where he is enrolled (public or not) and the one the players own

So simply put: ASKING the right question is the most important thing to solve a query.